# If statement not registering

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm creating a gallery slider with 5 images. I've wrapped every 5 images in a div with a class.

What I'm trying to do is remove controls if there is only 1 page of 5 images

```
var a = $('.truckgallery .gallery dl ');

    do $(a.slice(0,5)).wrapAll('<div class="f-slide"/>');
    while((a = a.slice(5)).length > 0)

    if( $('.f-slide').length < 1){
        $('.gal-nav').css('display' , 'none');
    }
```

When I run "$('.f-slide').length" in the console I receive back the correct number. I just can't get the if statement to pick it up.

Comment: `if` condition appear to evaluate after `$('.f-slide').length` greater than `1` ?

Comment: use `braces for blocks`

Answer (score 3):

Always use braces for block statements. Below code fixes the issue

```
do {
  $(a.slice(0,5)).wrapAll('<div class="f-slide"/>');
}while((a = a.slice(5)).length > 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a semicolon at the end of the `do...while` statement and remove the semi-colon at the end of the `do` line:

```
do $(a.slice(0,5)).wrapAll('<div class="f-slide"/>')
    while((a = a.slice(5)).length > 0);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/3445jrdy/

Comment: This is incorrect. Having the `;` after `do` will only execute the `do` once no matter what.

Comment: @nem you're correct, that is in the original question that I missed. The semi-colon after the `while` is still needed though.